# Hover effect: Change background color of other container when child container is hovered of other parent container (Using SCSS)

Tags: html, css, sass, hover, styling

I have a specific HTML structure in my React functional component and I'm trying to implement a hover effect.

I noticed that my question was marked as a duplicate due to similarities with existing CSS-related questions. However, I would like to clarify that my issue is specifically related to SCSS styling.

I have thoroughly reviewed the solutions provided for the CSS questions, but unfortunately, they don't seem to address my problem when applied to SCSS. I've attempted each suggested solution, but the issue persists.

If anyone could provide guidance or suggestions specifically tailored to SCSS styling, I would greatly appreciate it.

The structure looks like this:

```
<div className='container_main'></div>

<div className='container'>
  <div className='container_child'></div>
</div>
```

I want to change the background color of **'container_main'** when **'container_child'** within **'container'** is hovered. Both containers have their own styling, and I'm using **SCSS** for the styles.

**Expected Behavior:**

When I hover over container_child within container, the background color of container_main should change.

**Additional Information:**

- I am using React functional components.
- The styles are written in SCSS format.